# VR with A-Frame a-assets not reading properly for .jpg material source

Tags: three.js, textures, virtual-reality, aframe, webvr

Swapped from Three.js to A-Frame. The following code works:

```
<a-assets>
    <img id="WhiteBricks" src="http://www.memorynova.com/Pix/Environment/3JS/WallBrickWhite.jpg"/>
</a-assets>

<a-entity geometry="primitive: box; width:288; height:108 depth:8" position="0 54 0" material="src:http://www.memorynova.com/Pix/Environment/3JS/WallBrickWhite.jpg; repeat: 2.45 .7"</a-entity>
<a-box color="red" width="18" height="8" depth="8" position="0 15 .02"></a-box>
```

When I use the `WhiteBricks` asset in the `a-box` it works fine, but,
when I try to use `#WhiteBricks` in the `a-entity`, it crashes the entire page. It previously worked in `a-entity` until I added repeat to tile the texture to the proper size.

Now the tiling works, and is properly sized, but I have to use the entire path to the jpg, and when not using assets, it loads the jpg each time I use it. I don't want extra memory overhead, and extra bandwidth for mobile users. Has anyone else dealt with this before? Is it a recent bug?

The exact way I typed it was:

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive: box; width:288; height:108 depth:8" position="0 54 0" material="#WhiteBricks; repeat: 2.45 .7"</a-entity>
```

Yesterday it flashed a white wall and then it disappeared,leaving just the red brick, and the page stopped.

Today it leaves the BLANK white wall, with no texture at all.

It is throwing an error in the console to line 177 of browser.js. I assume that is one of the A-Frame dependencies, as I never saw that error in Three.js.
The error is:

> core:schema:warn Unknown property `24` for component/system `material`. +0ms

I would return to Three.js but the glitch still exists where textures disappear when objects get too close together and the front becomes transparent at different angles, A-Frame has not done this yet.

I made the move to reduce memory load, but this seems to counteract that plan. I have many walls to load.

I made a small fiddle of the affected area:
https://jsfiddle.net/RonK/tjfwhdsd/16/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `>`. Use this code:

```
<a-entity position="0 54 0"></a-entity>
```

instead of this:

```
<a-entity position="0 54 0"</a-entity>
```

Removed some code to make it readable.